# Some Javascript variables not displaying in window when they should

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web form and I am using JQuery to pull values the user has input and display them on the screen with an additional string added to it.  The problem is that only two of the values are being displayed.  When I look at the debugger, I can see the variables are populated but they aren't showing up on the screen.

My web form:

```
<form method="POST" id="sas_form" action="#">
  <select name="var_type" id="var_type">
    <option value="1">1</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <input type="text" name="value" value="0" id="value">
  <input type="text" name="something" id="something">
  <a href="#" id="add-row">Add Another row</a>

  <div id="renderArea"></div>
</form>
```

My Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $('#add-row').click(function() {
    var var_type = $('#var_type').val();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var value = $('#value').val();
    var something = $('#something').val();

    $('#renderArea').append({'-Var VarType="'+var_type+'" Position="'+i+'"    
            Name="'+ name +'"><Imputed Value>' + value + '</Imputed Value>
            Something = ' + something});

    // increment the position
    i += 1;
  })
});
```

Comment: which two values are not showing up?

Comment: [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) read the manual and then check your `.append(...)` and its parameter ;)

Comment: It is unclear what you want the output to be, since what you have in `.append()` is not valid HTML.

Comment: I just want it to print the statement as it is written.  I can see where it might be trying to interpret the string as HTML when it clearly isn't.  I'll try wrapping it in a <p> tag.

Comment: I figured out what was going on... I need to replace all the <'s and >'s with the HTML entities.  That corrected the issue.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `.append()` statement to something like:

```
var html = '-Var VarType="' + var_type + '" Position="' + i + 
           '" Name="' + name + '"><Imputed Value>' + value + '</ImputedValue>' +
           'Something = ' + something;

$('#renderArea').append(html);
```

Note - `<Imputed Value></Imputed Value>` is not valid XML. No spaces in tag names. Since you're outputting it as HTML - that probably matters.

Your issue is likely to do with the fact that you were putting your `.append()` parameters inside a `{}` - which is not necessary.

Comment: I just want the string to be output to the window as it is written.  I will try putting it all into a variable and see what effect that has.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The solution was to replace all the > and < with HTML entities.